# How does taskRuntime get all tasks at once?

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

```
Page<org.activiti.api.task.model.Task> tasks = taskRuntime.tasks(Pageable.of(0, 30));
    for (org.activiti.api.task.model.Task task : tasks.getContent()) {
        System.out.println(task);
    }
```

- It must specify a maxitems.
- Can I use taskRuntime to get all tasks at once?
- Or can only use taskservice?
- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Page<org.activiti.api.task.model.Task> taskSize = taskRuntime.tasks(Pageable.of(0, 10));
Page<org.activiti.api.task.model.Task> taskList = taskRuntime.tasks(Pageable.of(0, taskSize.size()));

Then taskList has all tasks